# Why is "man" in "Snowman" pronounced differently than in "Frenchman" or "Englishman"?

Tags: pronunciation, demonyms

It seems that in the words *Englishman*, *Frenchman*, and *Scotsman*,
the *‑man* part is pronounced /mən/ (just like in *Roman*).

Whereas in *snowman*, the *‑man* part is pronounced /mæn/ (just
like in *no man*).

Why is it that when *‑man* is appended to *snow‑* to make *snowman*,
the pronunciation of the *man* part doesn’t change?

Wouldn’t it logically follow for it to be pronounced /ˈsnowmən/
not /ˈsnowˌmæn/?

Comment: Compare *mailman, sand-man, businessman, milkman, snow-man, mad-man, ice-man, middleman, ape-man, wise-man* with *bridesman, workman, marksman, draftsman, fireman, fisherman, freshman, policeman, countryman, showman, sportsman, toolsman, walkman, Welshman, coachman, dairyman*.

Comment: So this begs the question, why are "Englishman", "Frenchman", "Scotsman" pronounced differently?

Comment: One explanation is that “new” noun–noun compounds like *snow-man* and *ape-man* tend not to lose the stress on the second syllable, while adjective–noun compounds that are nationalities like *Cornishman* and *Welshman* tend to do so. But you may be hard-pressed to find an all-encompassing law that governs all cases, considering how many “old” noun–noun compounds of professions like *coachman* and *journeyman* have lost the secondary stress.  We'll see what people come up with.

Comment: I don't think there is a rule that governs the pronunciation. It is probably how the words were derived from Old English or other source language.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: No. For one thing, in OE they didn't call the residents of the country *Scotsmen* but *Scottas*, and the country itself was *Scotta lande*. The word Scotsman itself was not used until the late 14th century. Englishman was *Engliscman* (pronounced with initial and final stresses). (N.B. the *sc* in Old English was prounced like our *sh*.) The OE for Frenchmen would have been *frencisce men* (or *menn*) with a stress on *men* as you would say it today if separated into two different words.

Comment: "Snowman" is a noun-noun compound and so has primary-secondary stress, but "Frenchman" is not a compound (though etymologically it might have derived from one) and so has the same stress a morphologically simple word would have.

Comment: @tchrist If your list is structured the way I suspect (compare examles of full-vowel /man/ with examples of reduced-vowel /mən/), it’s a good indicator of the variation that exists. I pronounce _businessman_ and _milkman_ with /ə/, and _countryman_ and _dairyman_ variably with /a ~ ə/, going against your groupings. The former are supported by dictionaries; the latter not at a quick glance. I also have no preference either way with _snowman_: full /a/ and reduced /ə/ are equally possible for me.

Comment: @GregLee That is, I believe, essentially the right answer on the face of it: the difference is whether or not a word is perceived as a compound (noun-noun, adjective-noun, verb-noun, probably others as well), or whether it’s perceived as a single unit. That doesn’t answer the _underlying_ question, though: since all of these originated as compounds, why have only some been reinterpreted as single units, while others remain compounds? The age of the compound and the type of its first constituent are probably both factors, but there must be others, because the end result is quite random.

Comment: @Janus: You pronounce it *milkmən*? I can't recall ever hearing that pronunciation. What dialect do you speak, or is that idiolectical?

Comment: @Robusto I would at least vacillate between /mɪlkman/ and /mɪlkmən/, probably more likely to end up with the latter than the former. Not really a word I use a lot in general, though, since the disappearance of the trade. My dialect varies between fairly generic BBC BrE and fairly generic Broadcast AmE, depending on context. I _think_ I’d be more likely to go with /a/ in AmE than in BrE. ([ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/milkman) also gives /ə/, so that probably is a more BrE variant.)

Answer (score 4):

In a comment to the original question, Greg Lee wrote the following brief answer:

> "Snowman" is a noun-noun compound and so has primary-secondary stress, but "Frenchman" is not a compound (though etymologically it might have derived from one) and so has the same stress a morphologically simple word would have.

Answer (score 0):

I am finding, by experimentation, that it is a purely physical matter of how my lips are poised on ending the first syllable and how they prepare for the next syllable.

'Snowman' requires an 'oma' in the middle which is comfortable to say.
'Englishman' would need a 'shma' which is not comfortable. So I produce a 'shmi' sound instead.

This is purely subjective to myself, I must point out.

Comment: Are you certain this is a matter of comfort? If your thesis were true, then we should not be able to distinguish in pronunciation the two contrasting cases of ❶  "When an *English **man*** marries a *French **man***” (which is actually gender-specific) versus ❷ "When an *Englishman* marries a *Frenchman*” (which is generic and so no longer gender-specific). The first case has no reduction to unstressed schwa in the respective “man” elements—yet the second case ***does*** undergo reduction, despite the two sequences being otherwise the same. Doesn't that disprove your comfort hypothesis?

Comment: The notion behind this is often called ‘ease of pronunciation’ in linguistics, but it’s a red herring. While there are a limited set of near-universal developments that can be said to be almost universally considered ‘easier’ to pronounce, the vast majority of things people consider ‘easier’ is purely down to familiarity with words pronounced like that—which is wide of the mark and not relevant here. There is no physiological difference in ease of pronunciation between /a/ and /ə/ in this case, regardless of the previous syllable.

Answer (score 0):

The all-encompassing law that covers all cases is that the pronunciation of the ‘man’ suffix depends on uniqueness. Where uniqueness occurs, the original pronunciation of ‘man’ is preserved. Where uniqueness does not occur, the pronunciation of ‘man’ is reduced as noted.

So, considering specific cases: You have only one milkman, there is only one sand-man, ‘businessman’ is usually cited only in a context where it is a unique reference, you have only one milkman, there is only one snowman (and his name is ‘Frosty’!), and so on, so these all have the original pronunciation of ‘man’, whereas ‘Englishman’, ‘Frenchman’, ‘fisherman’, ‘draftsman’, ‘coachman’ etc. are all decidedly non-unique, and so have a reduced pronunciation of ‘man’.

Comment: I was going to take issue with your "only one milkman/businessman" assertion, and still disagree. But the pronunciation of many of these profession or role examples is actually rather fluid anyway. Certainly in plenty of the southern English accents with which I'm familiar, the last syllable  is often unstressed/schwa.

Comment: I utterly fail to see how you have only one milkman, but not only one coachman. They are completely equivalent in their uniqueness.